# I have a few JSON files that are empty and are giving an exception when I try to loop through them. How do I make this work?

Tags: python, json, csv, web-scraping

I'm doing some research on Cambridge Analytica and wanted to have as much news articles as I can from some news outlets.

I was able to scrape them and now have a bunch of JSON files in a folder.
Some of them have only this `[]` written in them while others have the data I need.

Using pandas I used the following and got every webTitle in the file.

```
df = pd.read_json(json_file)
df['webTitle']
```

The thing is that whenever there's an empty file it won't even let me assign `df['webTitle']` to a variable.

Is there a way for me to check if it is empty and if it is just go to the next file? 
I want to make this into a spreadsheet with a few of the `keys` and columns and the `values` as rows for each news article.

My files are organized by day and I've used TheGuardian API to get the data.

I did not write much yet but just in case here's the code as it is:

```
import pandas as pd
import os


def makePathToFile(path):
    pathtoJson = []
    for root,sub,filename in os.walk(path):
        for i in filename:
            pathToJson.append(os.path.join(path, i))
    return pathToJson




def readJsonAndWriteCSV (pathToJson):
    for json_file in pathToJson:
        df = pd.read_json(json_file)
```

Thanks!

Comment: You have to ask a specific programming question on stack and show an example of your own attempt at using the code. I would attempt to scrape first, and if you have any errors ask a specific question. That’s the nature of the stack rules.

Comment: I see! I'm kind of new here and thought I could have some tips before I start without even knowing if it is possible haha

Comment: Please take a look at this, https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask, then see if you can edit your question to prevent it being closed as 'Too Broad'.

Comment: You may want to start with a way of [getting data from a web page](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/).

Comment: @GabrielAlmeida that’s fine Gabriel. As vasxowhite stated, edit your question later so that it is not closed, and if you have any specific questions, ask away and show an example of your code, and we will be available to help!

Comment: @SimeonIkudabo I've accomplished a few things but got stuck on others now hahah

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a [google Alert](https://www.google.com.au/alerts) for the news keywords you want, then scrape the results in python using https://pypi.org/project/galerts/